# How to stop a cat from waking me up?

Tags: cats, behavior

I have a cat that likes to start his day off early (e.g. 5am) where he starts batting items around (boxes i leave out for him and toys and sometimes items he shouldnt), running from one room to the other, and trying to scratch my door frames (previous family I adopted him from removed his claws so this is not an issue but it can be loud still). He also jumps on my bed and presses his face against my hand and lays on my head. Is there some way to discourage him from waking up so early or at least being hyper in the morning?

Comment: Hooman! Don't disobey your furry master! Slaves obey, they don't set the rules! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't reward the behavior. When they are too rough in waking you toss them off the bed, or hit them with a squirt from a spray bottle, or hiss at them, or firmly and loudly say "no!", or some combination of these. Cats are quite capable of learning which behaviors get them favorable attention and which produce responses they don't like.

Also, rambunctious behavior does drop off as they age out of  being kittens. So this eventually valves itself. My two mostly just cuddle against me if I'm sleeping, though one sometimes wants me to lift the covers so she can crawl under, and both want to kneed my belly for a few minutes before we all go to sleep. (Not always permitted.)

Answer (score 1):

NO! Aside from trying to keep them up late so they sleep in late...like a child. The answer is no. You can try to keep them away from the option to wake you. That could be bedroom door closed, or teflon walls. They will be up after a set time....you can only change with sleeping schedule...or not having access to you in themorning.

Answer (score 0):

Cats are neither diurnal nor nocturnal, they are crepuscular: They are most active in the twilight hours around dawn and dusk. This is normal healthy behavior for them, so it would not be good for your cat to be forced into doing otherwise.

If you feed them in the morning when you wake up they may quickly learn to wake you up when they think they should be fed. If you get up and feed them when they are trying to wake you up, their behavior will be reinforced. Your cat may also be concerned that something is wrong with you if they think you are oversleeping and they may try to see if you are responsive and get you up and moving.

As Keshlam suggested you can be firm with your cat and let them know you do not want to woken up. If you give in after a while then they will just learn to be persistent.

If their behavior and the noise it is a problem, lock the cat out of your bedroom, or isolate them in another part of your home.